# Some questions about Riemann integration

Tags: real-analysis

I just learn some basic definition about

Let $f, g:[0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be

$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x \in \Bbb Q$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x=1/n, n=1,2,...$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

We know $f$ is not Riemann integrable, but $g$ is.

So my first question is, is it true that if the set of discontinuous points is a dense set, then that function is not Riemann integrable.

My second question is we know $h:[0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ by $h(x)=1$ is integrable and has value $1$. So if we have a dense set $D$ in $[0,1]$ which cardinality of $D$ and $D^c$ are equal, and define  $ u(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x \in D$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Can we define a similar 'integral' to say  the value of the 'integral' = $1/2$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is no. [Thomaes's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function) is discontinuous at the rational points and continuous at the irrationals, and Riemann integrable.

As for the second question, consider the following example. Let $a\in(0,1)$ and $f_a\colon[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ defined as
$$
f_a(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }x\in([0,a]\cap\Bbb Q)\bigcup([a,1]\setminus\Bbb Q),\\
0 & \text{if }x\in([0,a]\setminus\Bbb Q)\bigcup([a,1]\cap\Bbb Q).
\end{cases}$$
Any *reasonable* measure would give $\int_0^1f_a=1-a$, and not $1/2$.